# Duplicate data is coming in my report because source table has duplicate data

Tags: mysql, reporting-services

> duplicate data is coming in my report because source table has
>   duplicate data.

without creating group, I want to hide duplicate data writing expression. so what I did...I select table row and put a expression for hidden property of table row.

the expression was like

**=(Previous(Fields!ID.Value) = Fields!ID.Value)**

but it did not work...still duplicate data is showing. so tell me how to suppress duplicate row in **ssrs** writing expression not by grouping.

Please assist me to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: use can use distinct in mysql

Comment: Try using 'DISTINCT' http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Answer (score 0):

u did not gave a demo code u are using, so I am giving all possible solutions here.

If u are using **[Laravel Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-collections)** then your solution would be like this-

```
$uniqueCollection = $collection->unique();
```

If u are using MySQL then using `DISTINCT` is your best choice.

More can be found **[here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx)**.

With [**Laravel Query Builder**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries) or **[Eloquent Model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent)** that can be like this-

```
$data = $prev_fetched_data->distinct()->get();
```